# Are ArgoCD metrics enabled?

Tags: prometheus, argocd

Are ArgoCD metrics enabled by default? How can one determine that state? How can I change that state (if needed)?

I am trying to figure out how to make ArgoCD metrics available to Prometheus. If I open Prometheus, there are no `argocd_*` metrics available. I'm guessing I need to add some sort of scrape configuration to the Prometheus config, but I need to first determine whether ArgoCD is even making anything available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question since no one else seems to know. Yes, ArgoCD metrics are enabled by default.

Comment: Okay, were you able to get the metrics in prometheus? I have enabled metrics for argocd from it's helm chart and I don't seem to query for any argocd metrics. 
Note: I have vanilla prometheus - not the operator, and I don't have any `serviceMonitor` CRD to use as argocd docs show.